# Scheme Path In Binary Tree

Tags: scheme

I got an exercice to find the path of a binary tree in Scheme.
Basically, it's like Find all paths from root to leaves of tree in Scheme.
But instead of printing the value of nodes, we have to print the way to get to the leaf. ( print : right left left right for ex)

Comment: Please see my answer below for guidance on how to improve this question

Comment: Hama, do you have any code to show that you have made any effort in solving it?

Comment: Hint: add a function parameter that contains "the path so far".

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about finding the path from root to a specific leaf you can basically search your tree recursively and while doing that you should pass a list to your search function as parameter to keep track of the path already taken and your search function should return path list.

For example, let's say you are searching for L in your tree, you need to check whether L is in left or right subtree. After finding the subtree in which L is located you can basically add the direction to your path list, you can do something like

```
(define (search L tree)
    (cond  
          ((null? tree) '()  )
          ((member L leftsubtree ) (cons 'left (search L leftsubtree))
          ((member L rightsubtree) (cons 'right (search L rightsubtree)))))
```

What we do here is we found the subtree L is located and then add the direction (left or right) to the front of the path from parent of that subtree to L. Of course if you copy and paste this code it does not work. So you need to implement this function in accordance with your tree representation, and you probably need to implement member function for your case. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (ab-chemin-aux AB e CH)
(if (ab-noeud? AB)
(if (equal? e (ab-etiquette AB))
CH
(or (ab-chemin-aux (ab-gauche AB) e (append CH (list "gauche")))
(ab-chemin-aux (ab-droit AB) e (append CH (list "droit")))))#f))
(define (ab-chemin AB e)
(ab-chemin-aux AB e (list)))
```

I figured out the answer but I forgot about asking here. Thank you for your answer. Hope this help someone